# Is it possible to access the Android manifest from inside an AIR app?

Tags: android, air

I'm trying to automate updates for a private (off-market) AIR app. The app needs to know its version number as listed in the manifest. Obviously I can update this in a constant in the compiled app itself, but I'd rather if it could read its own manifest and figure out what version it is. Is there any way to access the versionLabel, versionNumber or other info from the XML manifest from within a running AIR app on Android?